# Chamar evento da GridView na Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gridview

Tenho um **GridView adapter** e nele possuo um `ImageButton` para excluir os itens. Ele está excluindo corretamente, porém, toda vez que um item for excluído preciso setar a quantidade atual em um `TextView` que está em uma outra `Activity`. Não consigo pegar o evento do `GridView` diretamente, pois, como ele possui outros componentes clicáveis, seu toque ficou desabilitado:

Segue o trecho de código em que excluo o item e tento passar a quantidade atual de itens para o `TextView` presente na minha `Activity`:

```
holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();


                Produto_Valor newList[] = new Produto_Valor[values.length - 1]; 
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    if (values.length - 1 > 0) {
                        if (values[i] == values[1]) {                    
                        } else {
                            newList[count] = values[i];
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                values = newList; 
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pedidos, null);
            final TextView txtTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_QtdeDados);



            new Thread (new Runnable(){
                @Override


                public void run(){

                    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(values.length));
                }
            }).start();




            }
        });
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema Fabio, ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Eu acho que uma solução que pode te ajudar é utilizar o método [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html), você pode ir na documentação do Android ou dar uma lida neste tutorial em pt-br: http://celeiroandroid.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/atividades.html, no final do tutorial é explicado o que é e como utilizar o *startActivityForResult*.

Para o seu problema acredito que você deseja duas Activities uma com a lista de itens e outra que possui este TextView com a quantidade de itens removidos. Você irá retornar a quantidade de itens de uma Activity para outra, não será necessário utilizar o método inflate para o item TextView na Activity de listagem dos itens.

Comment: Na verdade, tenho uma Activity e um Adapter, que extends  de BaseAdapter. Implementei da forma como você sugeriu, mas obtive o seguinte erro: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{aplicativo.App/aplicativo.App.GridViewAdapter_ItensPedido}: java.lang.ClassCastException: aplicativo.App.GridViewAdapter_ItensPedido cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função na sua `activity` para atualizar o `TextView`, por exemplo `atualizaTextView(String value)`. Aí no momento em que você chamar seu `imgDelete.setOnClickListener` você executa o método desta forma:

```
((MinhaActivity)context).atualizaTextView(value);
```

Boa sorte.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode abrir a activity do GridView, deletar os itens e depois retornar a quantidade de itens para a activity do TextView.

Na activity com o GridView (irei nomear GridViewActivity) deve chamar o método [`setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) no encerramento. Substitua o `finish()` em GridViewActivity como a seguir:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    // insere a quantidade de itens no Intent
    data.putExtra("TamanhoDaLista", tamanhoDaLista);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    super.finish();
}
```

Na activity que contém o TextView (vou chamar de TextViewActivity), coloque a constante no topo que será usada para identificar a GridViewActivity quando ela for finalizada:

```
private static final int REQUEST_DELETE_ITENS = 0; // zero é só um exemplo
```

Quando iniciar a GridViewActivity, use:

```
startActivityForResult(REQUEST_CODE, intent);
```

Substitua o método [`onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // verifica se o código de retorno é a GridViewActivity
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DELETE_ITENS) {
        // verifica se a activity retornou com sucesso (talvez tenha um botão cancelar)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // -1 se o valor não extiver presente no Intent (talvez esqueceu do putExtra?)
            textView.setText(data.getLongExtra("TamanhoDaLista", -1));
        }
    }
}
```

Se na GriViewActivity tiver um botão cancelar e salvar, coloque o código do `finish()` em salvar e no cancelar use `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma interface na GridViewAdapter:

```
    public class SeuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeuAdapter.SeuViewHolder> {

       private SeuAdapter.SeuOnClickListener SeuOnClickListener;

        /**
         * construtor
         * @param context
         * @param seuOnClickListener
         */
        public MesaAdapter(Context context, SeuAdapter.SeuOnClickListener seuOnClickListener) {
            this.seuOnClickListener = seuOnClickListener;
        }

//interface
            public  interface GridViewOnClickListener{
                public  void onClickGridView(View view, int idx);
            }

    //no metodo onBindViewHolder:

        @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final MesaAdapter.MesaViewHolder holder, final int position) {

               ...

                if (gridOnClickListener != null){
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            gridOnClickListener.onClickSeu(holder.itemView, position);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Ai na outra classe que chama e controla o GridView você faz a declaracao da interface;

```
    private SeuAdapter.SeuOnClickListener onClickSeu(){
        return  new SeuAdapter.SeuOnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClickSeu(View view, int idx) {
                //execucao
            }
        };
    }
```